# Leer un txt y llenar labels con la informacion dentro. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, programación-bajo-nivel

se que soy nuevo espero mi pregunta no sea muy tonta.

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con un codigo para leer un txt y que el contenido de los labels se adapte a lo que yo escriba en ese txt. Me explico.

Digamos que tengo label1, label2 y labe3. Y dentro del archivo TXT tengo en la primera linea "Arbol", en la segunda "Animal" y en la tercera "Persona" se veria algo asi:

Arbol
Animal
Persona

Entonces, el label1.text seria = Arbol, el label2.text seria = Animal y el label3.text seria = Persona, claro si yo cambio esas lineas tambien lo haria dentro del window form una vez reiniciada la aplicacion, ojo, el texto estara en la direccion por defecto del application startup path.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Si te refieres a un objeto Label de Windows Form, entonces puedes leer todo el fichero txt, separar las líneas y obtener un array de string de 3 elementos. Y asignar a cada Label un string del array. Por ejemplo: label1.Text = textos[0];

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = "/texto.txt";
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string texto = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lineas = texto.Split('\n');

    Label[] labels = new Label[]{label1, label2, label3};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        labels[i].Text = lineas[i];
    }
}
```